# Querying multiple mySQL tables in a single query

Tags: mysql, join

I need to write a query for a scout database that compares the requirements of a badge with the skills a given member has already earned. The purpose being that several skills are applicable to multiple badges. My relevant tables (there are many) look like this:

**Badge_Table**:
*Badge_ID*,
Badge_Name,
Badge_Description,

**Badge_Skills_Table**:
*Badge_Skill_ID*,
Badge_ID,
Skill_ID,

**Skills_Table**:
*Skill_ID*,
Skill_Name,
Skill_Description,

**Skills_Earned_Table**:
*Skills_Earned_ID*
Skill_ID
User_ID

**User_Table**:
*User_ID*,
Name,
Age,
Address

Primary keys are shown in italics, and the foreign key relationships go from Badge_table to Badge_Skills_Table to Skills_Table to Skills_Earned_table to User_Table.

So far I have came up with the following ideas:

### Selects all badges for named skill

```
SELECT badge_table.badge_name
FROM (badge_table 
     INNER JOIN badge_skills_table ON badge_ID 
     INNER JOIN Skills_Table ON skill_Id)
WHERE Skills_Table.Skill_Id = 1;
```

### Selects all badges for each skill

```
SELECT badge_table.badge_name
FROM (badge_table 
      INNER JOIN badge_skills_table ON badge_ID 
      INNER JOIN Skills_Table ON skill_Id)
WHERE Skills_Table.Skill_Id = Skill_Badge_Table.Skill_Id
```

### Selects all badges for named skill for named User - not quite working

```
SELECT badge_table.badge_name
FROM (badge_table 
     INNER JOIN badge_skills_table ON badge_ID 
     INNER JOIN Skills_Table ON skill_Id 
     INNER JOIN Skills_Earned_Table On skill_ID 
     INNER JOIN users_table ON user_ID)
WHERE Skills_Earned_Table.User_ID= 1 AND Skills_Earned_Table.SKILL_ID = Skill_Badge_Table.skill_ID
```

So can anyone help guide me with the following:

1. How to return all badges that a given skill is applicable for. (Done)
2. How to return all badges that a given scout has earned skills towards.
3. To return all badges the a given scout has earned all the skills for.

I'd appreciate any help you can offer,

Comment: All your `ON` clauses are wrong. They need to be a comparison, e.g. `ON badge_skills_table.badge_ID = badge_table.badge_id`.

Comment: There's no need to put parenthese around all the `INNER JOIN` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `<conditions>` in your `ON` clause. Try my query below:

```
SELECT A.badge_name
FROM badge_table A
     INNER JOIN badge_skills_table B ON A.badge_ID=B.badge_ID
     INNER JOIN Skills_Table C ON B.skill_Id=C.skill_ID
     INNER JOIN Skills_Earned_Table D ON C.skill_ID=D.skill_ID 
     INNER JOIN users_table E ON user_ID ON D.user_ID=E.user_ID
WHERE D.User_ID= 1 AND D.skill_ID = B.skill_ID
```

Comment: Assuming the columns strong the same data type, OP could have used `USING` instead of `ON`. This would join the table on the specified column which is present in both tables.